# Width between two lines in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to calculate width between two lines in a EditText ?

If so how can I do that ? I need to calculate the number of lines that an EditText can take with the given height of it ! I can get the text width and I need to get the line width too .. but I dont know how to find that ..

Can anyone help me regarding this !!

Thanks,

Siva Kumar

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this? :

> ```
> public int getLineBounds (int line, Rect bounds) Since: API Level 1
> ```
>
> Return the baseline for the specified
> line (0...getLineCount() - 1) If
> bounds is not null, return the top,
> left, right, bottom extents of the
> specified line in it. If the internal
> Layout has not been built, return 0
> and set bounds to (0, 0, 0, 0)
>
> Parameters
>
> *line* which line to examine
> (0..getLineCount() - 1)
>
> *bounds* Optional. If not null, it returns the
> extent of the line
>
> Returns
>
> the Y-coordinate of the baseline

[Link to the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLineBounds(int,%20android.graphics.Rect))